# Likes is multiplying comment numbers?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql select to get posts, likes it has, comments.
The problem is I notice that if one post has, for example, 2 like or more it will multiply the comments number.

eg: user has 2 comments in real.

```
1 like - 2 comment
2 likes - 4 comments (user has 2, but will show 4)
3 likes - 6 comments (user has 2)
```

Can see that likes is, somehow, multiplying comments.

What is wrong in my query?

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.titulo, p.youtube, pp.foto, count(DISTINCT likes.user) as likes_count, SUM(CASE comentarios.delete WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
as comentarios_count, count(DISTINCT l2.user) as count2 from posts p 
join cadastro c on p.user=c.id 
left join profile_picture pp on p.user = pp.user
left join likes on likes.post = p.id // here?
left join comentarios on comentarios.foto = p.id
left join likes l2 on l2.post = p.id and l2.user = '1'
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit 10
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes` (
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `post` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `user_post` (`user`,`post`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`post`) REFERENCES posts (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comentarios` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foto` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `texto` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`foto`) REFERENCES posts (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

If need another table, please, ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get like, comment with different query. because you have joined them but they are not inter related with each other, likes and comment are belongs to post, so you have create a query that get posts likes and a query for comments do not mix it on database level, you have to manage it through code, You can manage the counter on post table using update query on every like and comment if you want. Hope you get my point...

Comment: I did it on php: $comments / $likes = real comments number. it is a hack but works...

Comment: It's not work always and not a good practice to work. you know that...:)